# Reject $.when with promise object?

Tags: jquery

Am I able to reject a $.when deferred function?

For example:

```
var promise = $.when(somefunc, somefunc2).done(function(){ ... });
promise.reject();
```

I understand that this isn't how promises work, but is there a way to still use $.when alongside reject?

Comment: what you exactly want? call one function after another ah?

Comment: No, I want to be able to prevent the when function from finishing. For example, if the user leaves the page, I don't want the "done" function to run.

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem. Or like it can turn into one. **No, you can't reject a deferred object if all you have is the promise**

Comment: So, you want to "stop" the promise, not "reject" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it all by hand:

```
var rejected = false;
$.when(somefunc, somefunc2).done(function(){
   if(!rejected){
      // ...
   }
});

rejected = true;
```

Comment: there's a small logic problem in your code, you're executing `callIfNotRejected` immediately rather than when done.

Comment: Small, but fatale! I'm sorry. I've updated it, but now it does not work on general purposes anymore.